# SVG stripes with 2 colors

Tags: css, svg

In this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ywb77uhv/

Why does when changing the strip path color to other than white it breaks the render? How to be able to change the path color?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>

    #stripe path {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    .stripe {
      mask: url("#mask");
    }
    .blue.stripe {
      fill: #00f;
    }
    .red.stripe {
      fill: #f00;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg height="500" width="500">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4">
      <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2
               M0,4 l4,-4
               M3,5 l2,-2" />
    </pattern>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect height="100%" width="100%" style="fill: url(#stripe)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <g class="stripe">
      <rect width="100" height="50" y="0" />
    </g>
    <g class="red stripe">
      <rect width="100" height="50" y="50" />
    </g>
    <g class="blue stripe">
      <rect width="100" height="50" y="100" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in SVG, a mask uses the luminance of the colors in the mask definition to calculate the alpha value of the mask. White = 100% opacity. Red = 70ish% opacity, blue= teens opacity.